# Why doesn't my Alt+F2 work?

Tags: 11.04, gnome-panel

I just noticed that my **Alt+F2** no longer works in **Ubuntu Classic**. It was working fine just yesterday when I restored **gnome-panel** after not liking AWN. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Install **CompizConfig
  Settings Manager**:

  `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
- Launch it by searching from the dash
  in **Unity**, or <kbd>Preferences</kbd> →
  <kbd>CompizConfig Settings Manager</kbd> in
  **Ubuntu Classic**.
- Navigate to the **Gnome
  Compatibility** tab.

[image]

- Make sure **Run Dialog** is set to
  **Alt+F2**, and not **disabled**.

[image]

Comment: That did it, Gnome Compatibility was checked, but the Run Dialog was set to disabled for some reason. Thanks mate!

Comment: Glad I could help Alan! You got me my 'close votes' badge O+

Comment: No, thank you! I'm trying to get Flight-Gear into shape, but I'll add some screenshots to this post later tonight for you.

Comment: In 16.10 if you activate Gnome compatibility, it wants to deactivate Unity plugin.